# Unable to add the value from dropdown list to end of url

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble trying to add the value part of the dropdown list to the end of my url as each value is different for the dropdown list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Task 8</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    change(val) {
      document.staff1.action="http://tl28serv/task7.php?staffID=" + val;
    }
  </script>

  <form id="StaffName" action="http://tl28serv/task7.php?staffID=" method="post">
    <select id="staff1">
      <option value="12">Perce Trainor</option>
      <option value="15">Chuck Norris</option>
      <option value="23">Jane Zumba</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not ?

Comment: `change()`  is `function change()` right? and when are you calling `change()`?

Comment: You are missing the `function` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `function` keyword. Also you need to call the function `change()` on `onchange` event. Do it like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function change(th) { //Added function keyword
      document.getElementById("StaffName").action="http://tl28serv/task7.php?staffID=" + th.value;
    }
  </script>

  <form id="StaffName" action="http://tl28serv/task7.php?staffID=" method="post">
    <select id="staff1" onchange="change(this)"> <!--Called change() here-->
      <option value="12">Perce Trainor</option>
      <option value="15">Chuck Norris</option>
      <option value="23">Jane Zumba</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fkg2zz5o/). Check console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle changed uri on server side and do nothing with it on client side, you don't have to do anything. just send data to server.

If you use `GET` method, your `id` appears on uri string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>Task 8</title>
</head>

<body>

 <form id="StaffName" action="http://tl28serv/task7.php" method="get">
   <select id="staffID">
      <option value="12">Perce Trainor</option>
      <option value="15">Chuck Norris</option>
      <option value="23">Jane Zumba</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are trying to set action on select box, that is not correct, you have to set action on form. I think this should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Task 8</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function change(val) {
  document.StaffName.action="http://tl28serv/task7.php?staffID=" + val;
}
  </script>

  <form id="StaffName" action="http://tl28serv/task7.php?staffID=" method="post">        
<select id="staff1" onSelect="change(this.value)">
  <option value="12" >Perce Trainor</option>
  <option value="15">Chuck Norris</option>
  <option value="23">Jane Zumba</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **JavaScript** to achieve this.

Here is how you do it with `HTML`

1. Change your form `method` to `GET`, instead of `POST`.
2. Change form `action` to `http://tl28serv/task7.php`
3. Add `name` attribute to `select`, with value `staffID`

Of course, there exists a Javascript solution as well.

Here is how you achieve it:

```
<body>
  <form id="StaffName" action="http://tl28serv/task7.php" method="post">
    <select id="staff1">
      <option value="12">Perce Trainor</option>
      <option value="15">Chuck Norris</option>
      <option value="23">Jane Zumba</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
  // move script 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var staff = document.getElementById('staff1');
    // attach "change" EventListener to #staff1
    staff.addEventListener('change', function() {
      document.getElementById('StaffName').action="http://tl28serv/task7.php?staffID=" + this.value;
    });
  </script>
</body>
```